# Is it possible to never grow a full beard

Tags: hair, facial-hair

I'm almost 30 now and have never been able to grow a full beard.

It's not a thick beard either and quite patchy in places especially around my cheeks and jawline.

My brothers have been able to grow thick full beards since they were teenagers but it doesn't look I can as last time I tried I grew it out for three months and it just looked like an old brush with bristles missing.

At this point I'm not sure it's possible but would be nice to read some success stories as I'm sure there are some.

Thanks

Comment: I would caution anyone answering to solely address the possibility, as personal anecdote stories are not on topic.

Comment: Trust me you are not alone. I'm 35 now and still have patches where facial hair doesn't grow densely enough to pull off a full beard. I even have quite dark hair/skin so actually I could grow a decent mustache or goatee, but these patches have been the same for years now so I've given up all hope that they will eventually "fill in".

Comment: @WillAppleby Thanks Will, strangely since writing this question i've noticed that instead of shaving with traditional razor just lightly shaving with the trimmer of an electric razor has stimulated some hair follicles into coming out. Im not really sure if its because those hairs tend to grow slower than the rest but ive definitely seen an improvement. Cheers for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Growing a beard is mostly due to genetics and your sensitivity to testosterone levels:

> When people have no facial hair, they tend to think it’s because of the fact that they have low testosterone. **That’s not the case, it’s actually based on how sensitive your body is to testosterone.** In other words, if you are highly sensitive to it, you’re going to have a lot more hair on your face and body. The good news for those without much or any facial hair is that they don’t have to worry about being bald later on in life
>
> <sup>[The Royal Beard Club](https://royalbeardclub.com/beards/how-to-grow-a-beard/is-beard-growth-all-genetics/)</sup>

---

As has been pointed out, a commercial site does have it's own interest. While I have been struggling through an advertisement jungle to find free sources that back up the first claim (hair growth is related to hair follicle sensitivity to testosterone), I have been able to find a source backing up the second claim (that hair loss is related to hair follicle sensitivity to testosterone):

> It’s not the amount of testosterone or DHT that causes baldness; **it’s the sensitivity of your hair follicles. That sensitivity is determined by genetics.** The AR gene makes the receptor on hair follicles that interact with testosterone and DHT. If your receptors are particularly sensitive, they are more easily triggered by even small amounts of DHT, and hair loss occurs more easily as a result. Other genes may also play a part.
>
> <sup>[Healthline.com](https://www.healthline.com/health/hair-loss-and-testosterone#genes)</sup>
>
> <sup>Alternatively [WebMD.com](https://www.webmd.com/skin-problems-and-treatments/hair-loss/hair-loss-causes-men)</sup>

---

So, to answer your question: Yes, it is totally possible to be unable to grow a beard, and there’s not much one can do about beard thickness.

Comment: While this answer seems to be exactly the type of thing needed here, I'd strongly caution against using a beard product seller as a source for medical information about beards, as they have strong motivations for bias.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Thanks for reminding me. I have included a second source that only backs up 50% though. As the beard product seller effectively tells you that no product will enhance bear growth, the motivation for a bias was limited. This is why I considered it as a source in the first place. // If you should run across a better source, feel free to point me towards it or write an answer yourself.